# Configure htaccess to work with IIRF on IIS6 - codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, iis-6, iirf

i just created a website with CodeIgniter, the problem was with our server that running on windows server 2003 with IIS6,

when calling the website it displays only the homepage, and the other pages displays 404 error page due to .htaccess limitation on IIS6,

the support told me that he did a setup for a program called IIRF to enable moderewrite but still i need to use another rewrite expression that the one was in the htaccess

here is my htaccess content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /root/

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^mvc/core_business.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^mvc.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
   # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
   # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in IIRF.ini :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase 

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^mvc/core_business.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^mvc.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: i have another issue, that when navigate to another page else the homepage it display 404 error page, when removing these line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^mvc/core_business.*` it display the page but without reading the css or images

Answer (score 0):

IIS does not support `.htaccess` files - that is [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org) feature.

You **have** to install the [IIRF](http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF) to have any rewriting at all, but still it will not be exactly the same.

See [IIRF](http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF) website for more information, or consider using Apache for Windows ;)